# Starting Edge Chromium in InPrivate mode / headless mode did not work for selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, headless-browser

I'm trying to start edge chromium in private mode during my selenium / java test.I also want to start it in headless mode. I tried some options, but none of them are working.

As per Microsoft site, (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=c-sharp) i passed UseChromium property as true. But still i am unable to get the headless and private browsing to work. Please provide your ideas.

Edge chromium version: Version 81.0.416.77 (Official build) (64-bit)
msedgedriver version: 81.0.416.77 (64-bit)
Selenium version: 3.141.59 (stable version)

My code:

```
EdgeOptions options=new EdgeOptions();
options.setCapability("UseChromium", true);
options.setCapability("InPrivate", true);
driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 3):

We could add argument `inprivate` to make Edge Chromium open in Private mode using Selenium WebDriver. And, add arguments `headless` and `disable-gpu` to make Edge Chromium open in headless mode using Selenium WebDriver.

Please check the following steps:

Step 1

Download the Java/C# binding of Selenium 4.00-alpha05 from [here](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).

Download the matching version of Microsoft Edge Driver from [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads).

Step 2:

**Open Edge Chromium in Private mode using Selenium WebDriver:**

Java Code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeOptions;

public class Edgeauto {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "D:\\webdriver\\msedgedriver.exe"); 
        EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
        edgeOptions.addArguments("-inprivate");
        WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions); 
        driver.get("https://bing.com");
    }
}
```

C# code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using System.Threading;

namespace ecwebdriver
{
    public class edgewebdriver
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
            edgeOptions.UseChromium = true;
            edgeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
            edgeOptions.AddArgument("-inprivate");
            var msedgedriverDir = @"E:\webdriver";
            var driver = new EdgeDriver(msedgedriverDir, edgeOptions);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://bing.com");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Open Edge Chromium in headless mode using Selenium WebDriver**

C# code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using System.Threading;

namespace ecwebdriver
{
    public class edgewebdriver
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
            edgeOptions.UseChromium = true;
            edgeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
            edgeOptions.AddArgument("headless");
            edgeOptions.AddArgument("disable-gpu");

            var msedgedriverDir = @"E:\webdriver";
            var driver = new EdgeDriver(msedgedriverDir, edgeOptions);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("<website url>");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: Change the webdriver paths and website url in the code to your owns.

If you want start edge chromium in private mode and headless mode. the EdgeOptions should as below:

```
        EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
        edgeOptions.UseChromium = true; 
        edgeOptions.AddArgument("-inprivate");
        edgeOptions.AddArgument("headless");
        edgeOptions.AddArgument("disable-gpu")
```

**Edit**

If using Selenium 3 version, we should add the [Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools) and [Selenium.WebDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/3.141.0) packages to our .NET project using the NuGet CLI or Visual Studio. More detail information, please check [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/edge-selenium-tools).

Then, add the following reference:

```
using Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools;
```

and refer to the following C# code (remember change the path to your owns):

```
        EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
        edgeOptions.UseChromium = true;
        edgeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
        edgeOptions.AddArgument("-inprivate");
        //edgeOptions.AddArgument("headless");
        //edgeOptions.AddArgument("disable-gpu");

        var msedgedriverDir = @"E:\webdriver\edgedriver_win64_81_0_416_77\edgedriver_win64";
        var driver = new EdgeDriver(msedgedriverDir, edgeOptions);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        driver.Close();
```

[Note] the EdgeOptions and EdgeDriver are in the `Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools` namespace, instead of the `OpenQA.Selenium.Edge` namespace.

Comment: I'm using stable version of selenium -> 3.141.59. With this i'm unable to get the addArguments() method from edgeoptions object. Can you kindly clarify for the same stable version?

Comment: @Sangeetha, please check my edit, install the Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools package and use it to create EdgeOptions and EdgeDriver, then you could add arguments.

Comment: Since I'm using java, can you please tell the equivalent package name in java?  Do we have any dependency from where we can download?

Comment: Sorry, as far as I know, the Selenium Tools don't have the Java version, and when using selenium 3 in Java, the EdgeOptions doesn't have the AddArgument method. So, I suggest you could download the Selenium 4.00-alpha05 version and use it to add the arguments.

Comment: @Sangeetha use `edgeOptions.setCapability()` instead.

Comment: Did anything worked for you @Sangeetha ? Were you able to run the edge chromium in headless mode using Java and selenium 3

Comment: @Gagan No, still on the same page.